# Can you configure a CDN to cache pages based on the browser language?

Tags: cdn, i18n

Many websites do not have the language or locale set in the URL string. They instead pull this out of the "Accept-Language" HTTP header. Is it possible with CDN's like CloudFlare and CloudFront to cache different versions of the page based on this header, or if not - what is the recommended best practice for this?

Comment: [Current best practice](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192) is to use different URLs for pages in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any particular CDN supports it, but you should be able to do it by setting `Vary: Accept-Language` in your responses.

Comment: So they don't support it, but doing vary: accept-language works?

Comment: `Vary: Accept-Language` is *supposed to*, by the RFCs, do the trick.  However, very few people who implement HTTP servers, clients, and proxies appear to have more than a passing familiarity with the HTTP specifications, so whether that header works as specified on any particular CDN is a crapshoot.